# Angular 2/4/6: how to update the scss dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I am trying to transform video using scss dynamically in Angular 2/4/6 (similar to this article:https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/)

I start 1st step is move video left /right / up / down

What I have done:

video.component.html

```
<div class="stage">
    <video controls autoplay loop [style.left.px] = "v" [style.top.px] = "h">
        <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="left()">
            Left
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="right()">
            Right
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="up()">
            Up
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="down()">
            Down
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

video.component.scss

```
.stage{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
  }
  video{
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
  -o-transform:scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
  transform:scale(1.5);
  }
```

video.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-video',
    templateUrl: './video.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']

})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {

    v: number = 0;
    h: number = 0;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    left(){
        this.v -= 5;
    }

    right(){
        this.v +=5;
    }
    up(){
        this.h -=5;
    }

    down(){
        this.h +=5;
    }
}
```

Result: nothing happens. Seems like scss is not updated at all.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with css for long, I found a working workaround:

video.component.html

```
<div class="stage">
    <video controls autoplay loop muted [ngStyle]="{'top': top, 'left': left, 'transform': 'scale('+ scale +')'}">
        <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
    </video>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveLeft()">
            Left
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveRight()">
            Right
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveUp()">
            Up
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveDown()">
            Down
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="zoomIn()">
            Zoom In
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="zoomOut()">
            Zoom Out
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

video.component.scss

```
.stage{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: coral
  }
  video{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
  }
```

video.component.ts

```
l: number = 0;
t: number = 0;
left = '0px';
top = '0px';

scale: number = 1;

moveUp() {
        this.t -= 5;
        this.top = this.t + 'px';
    }

    moveDown() {

        this.t += 5;
        this.top = this.t + 'px';

    }

    moveLeft() {
        this.l -= 5;
        this.left = this.l + 'px';
    }

    moveRight() {
        this.l += 5;
        this.left = this.l + 'px';
    }

    zoomIn() {
        this.scale += 0.2;

    }

    zoomOut() {
        this.scale -= 0.2;

    }
```

Although, it's working for me, this topic is still open for any better solution.

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Try ngStyle aproach

```
<video controls autoplay loop [ngStyle]="{'left.px': v, 'top.px': h}">
   <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: But before you try, check on the browser develop tools if charging left, top is really what you need. Maybe you need to do some translateX oy Y instead.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work with [ngStyle], instead of that, I used style = "..." . It doesn't work with left and right. I tried the  translateX and Y, I can move the video, however it destroyed the frame (.stage), and the scale of video (.video).

Comment: maybe you initial approach is working. but you chaging the wrong styles. as I said you need to try on the developing tools at your browser before